# How to properly call Dispose function to clear up resources when Shell is closing on all related ViewModels with Prism6 for WPF?

Tags: wpf, prism, viewmodel, dispose

What is the proper way to call related Dispose functions within several viewmodels, to ensure that these resources (objects) are successfully disposed before the shell window is closed? I'm using Prism (v6) in a WFP application.

Was trying to register the shell_viewmodel in the code-behind file of the shell view and then trigger a pubsub event to all subscribed viewmodels on the closing event of the shell, but the pubsub event is sadly never been fired, so the resources within the viewmodels are not being disposed.

The logic behind, I need to register a SQLTableDependency (SQLBroker) for several modules and want to close them, that the database listeners are being removed before the shell shuts down.

Any idea on this? I'm really struggling with this...

Comment: Can't you resolve a reference to the event aggregator in the `CreateShell()` method of the `Bootstrapper` and then handle the `Closing` event for the window?

Comment: Downvote? Sorry, not commenting but downvote... Sad that we cannot see, who is downvoting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Application.OnExit` to publish the event. You have to fetch the container instance from the bootstrapper and store it, of course, to resolve the event aggregator in `OnExit`.

Example:

```
internal partial class App
{
    protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnStartup( e );

        _bootstrapper = new MyBootstrapper();
        _bootstrapper.Run();
    }

    protected override void OnExit( ExitEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnExit( e );

        _bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<ApplicationExitingEvent>().Publish();
    }

    #region private
    private Bootstrapper _bootstrapper;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: May you please be a bit more precise?
How to bind on Application.OnExit event within App.cs, when UnityContainer is not yet constructed? It will be created after starting the Bootstrapper class later.

Comment: @SiL3NC3 this is really trivial, I don't understand the problem you're having, I guess... see my edit, anyway

Comment: I tried something similar, but the subscribed event aggregators are never firing, But okay... I'm dumb... please also down vote. It is really nice, feeling like an idiot!

Comment: @SiL3NC3 if the subscriber isn't notified, make sure that your're using the same instance of the event aggregator for publishing and subscribing (this can get wrong if you accidentally re-register or re-create the container), and that the subscriber (and the subscription) is alive and not garbage collected. I've tried the example, and my  subscribing view model received the event.

Comment: I'm using Prism for years now. I know how to use the container and registering objects and inject those within all viewmodels. But I have some troubles, that a listener for the database is not being disposed properly and connections are staying open.... However, I feeling sad, that I asked a "dumb" question and being downvoted for this. I give your approach a try in my project. Thank you for being still cooperative and helping! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @SiL3NC3 an altogether different approach would be to make the region manager dispose the view models (like here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/7) - this won't work with services, though, and I'm unsure whether it will work as expected when shutting down the application (the region manager might well just die instead of cleaning up his regions first)

Comment: Got it working via the registered Window_Closing event. Thank you Haukinger for your patience with me.